# Simple calculator program in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, calculator, calc

I am a newbie coder in Java and I am trying to make this calculator in java where a user can enter two numbers and select the operation to be done on those numbers. However when the code comes to selecting the operator it skips the user input and the if statement and directly implements the else statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Calc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n1;
        int n2;
        int Answer;

        System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
        n1 = Calc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number:" );
        n2 = Calc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Select the order of operation: ");
        char operator = Calc.nextLine().charAt(0);


        if (operator == '+') {
            Answer = (n1 + n2);
            System.out.println("Answer:" + Answer);
            } 
        if (operator == '-') {
            Answer = (n1 - n2);
            System.out.println("Answer:" + Answer);
            } 
        if (operator == '*') {
            Answer = (n1 * n2);
            System.out.println("Answer:" + Answer);
            } 
        if (operator == '/') {
            Answer = (n1/n2);
            System.out.println("Answer:" + Answer);
            } 
        else {
            System.out.println("not implemented yet. Sorry!");
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Comment: apart from your programming issue: you might want to check division by zero ;)

Comment: To explain the link with the duplicate topic, _nextInt()_ doesn't consume the "new line" expression, so add a _nextLine()_ instruction just after your second _nextInt()_ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Calc.nextLine();` after `n2 = Calc.nextInt();` to consume the line feed.

You are also not using `else if` so all those `if` conditions will be checked even if previous `if` already matched (resulting in your final else being executed as long as operator not `'/'`).

In this case you should probably just use a `switch` block.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to the code, this should work with you, but I also recommend using a switch.

Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int num1 = Input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter an operator: ");
        char operator = Input.next().charAt(0);

        System.out.print("Enter a second number: ");
        int num2 = Input.nextInt();
        // this part of decision, it doesn't work.
        if ('+' == operator) {
            System.out.println("Your result is " + (num1 + num2));
        } else if ('-' == operator) {
            System.out.println("Your result is " + (num1 - num2));
        } else if ('*' == operator) {
            System.out.println("Your result is " + (num1 * num2));
        } else if ('/' == operator) {
            System.out.println("Your result is " + (num1 / num2));
        }else {
            System.out.println("Your answer is not valid");
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("similar to try and except in Python");
    }
```